# How to write a grammar for this language?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

Given the alphabet $Λ = \{a, b, c\}$, i need to write a grammar for this language:

$$L=\{α \mid α∈Λ^+ ∧ aaa \notin α\}$$

I know that in my language the sequence of three consecutive $a$ cannot occur in any string, but how do I make a grammar of it? I'd need the thinking behind the construction of the grammar (like what's the first thing you should consider?), because so far I only manage to go by instinct and this doesn't always work.

Comment: This is a regular language, so you can construct an NFA and convert it into a grammar.

Comment: From the NFA I constructed, that's the grammar that came out:

$$ S → a | b | c | aA | bA | cA $$
$$ A →a | b | c | bA | cA | aB $$
$$ B → b | c | bA | cA $$

So i should always build the NFA before writing the grammar? With all kind of languages?

Comment: This is just one way to construct a CFG when the language happens to be regular. Of course, there are context-free languages which aren't regular, and this method wouldn't work for them.

Comment: Indeed, for example with this non-regular language: 

$$ L= \{ aba^n b^m a^n |n,m>0 \} $$ 

what's the best way to start?  Every string has to start with $ab$, then we have $aba$, and this part has to have the same number of $a$.

Comment: If you have a different question, ask it separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your language is regular, and so one way to construct a context-free grammar for it is to first consider a finite state automaton, and then convert it to a grammar. Of course, this methodology only works for regular languages, and is not necessarily the easiest way in every case.